# java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: hdfs in R Programming

Tags: r, hadoop

```
Sys.setenv(HADOOP_CMD="/home/hduser/hadoop-2.7.7/bin/hadoop")
Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.191.b12-0.el7_5.x86_64")

library(rhdfs)

hdfs.init()
```

I have run the above code to connect hdfs through R but I get the below error. please help me out of this.

```
Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl,  : 
  java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: hdfs
```

Comment: Try adding `Sys.setenv(HADOOP_HOME="/home/hduser/hadoop-2.7.7")` and `Sys.setenv(HADOOP_CONF_DIR="/home/hduser/hadoop-2.7.7/conf")`

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that your Hadoop config files are not being loaded

One way to do that via R would be to set

```
Sys.setenv(HADOOP_HOME="/home/hduser/hadoop-2.7.7")
Sys.setenv(HADOOP_CONF_DIR="/home/hduser/hadoop-2.7.7/conf")
```

Otherwise, you should set those variables at the OS level for all processes to read, e.g. `/etc/profile` or `.bashrc`